# Regular expression detects phone numbers correctly but not when phone numbers are inline

Tags: regex, phone-number

I'm trying to remove Dutch phone numbers from a string via a regular expression. The phone numbers to remove can contain spaces, and dashes and the country code.

These are typically used formats to be detected:

```
06-12345678
0612345678
0612345678
0101234567
010-1234567
010 1234567
010 12 34 567
010 12 34567
010 1234 567
+31612345678
0031123456789
```

So far I have: `^(?:0|(?:\+|00) ?31 ?)(?:(?:[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){8})|(?:6 ?-? ?[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){7})|(?:[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]\d ?-? ?[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){6})|(?:[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]\d{2} ?-? ?[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){5}))$`

This works perfect when phone numbers are on a separate line but NOT when they're inline like so:

> this is a list of numbers inline 06-12345678 gggf0612345678 06 12345678  0101234567 010-1234567 dfgfdg010 1234567

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/jOEFwS/2

I've checked here, but that is for US phone numbers:

- [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

How can I change my expression to capture inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `^` from the start and `$` at the end.

Some more info:
In regex101 you have the m flag, which makes ^ and $ line based, without it ^ is start of string and $ is end of string.